# UITableViewCell overlapping issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hello

Now I've been trying to display html links in a UITableView. 
I've been trying to do this via adding instances of UITableViewCell to the tableview's subview.

```
func updateViewController(){
    for name : String in currentDirectoryNames {
        var pusher = UITableViewCell();
        pusher.textLabel?.text = name;
        listView.addSubview(pusher);
    }
}
```

Sadly the result ends up with the text overlapped in one row :(
 [It looks like this...](http://puu.sh/dobVu.png)
Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's just adding your subview at with `origin.y` equal to 0 (looking like they're all on top of each other). There may be an easier way, but you may have to do something like set `pusher.frame.origin.y` to dynamically calculate based on which cell is being added.

Comment: @SeeMeCode thanks man did the trick! <a href="http://puu.sh/dosS8.png"> :D </a>

Comment: Awesome, I'll add it as an answer in case others are having the same issue!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The func you're calling is adding all of your subviews with origin.y equal to 0 (which makes them look like they're all on top of each other). You may have to do something like set pusher.frame.origin.y to dynamically calculate based on which cell is being added.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how UITableView works, at all. I highly suggest you read Apple's documentation on [TableView Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). At the very least, you'll need to set your view controller as the `dataSource` for the table view and implement the `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods.